# unable to ssh from host(windows 7) to linux installed on virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

i have installed redhat linux on virtual box running on windows 7 hostmachine.
Now i need to ssh from windows to linux.
windows ip address 192.168.1.152
gateway: 192.168.1.2

ethernet adapter virtual box hostonly network
ip address 192.168.56.1

Linux ip address 10.0.2.15
gateway 10.0.2.2
i am able to connect to internet from linux. Please suggest how to ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual networking you used is NAT, if you want to connect to redhat via ssh then add port forwarding rules in virtual box.

[image]

And use localhost as IP address in putty.

Make sure SSH daemon is running in redhat.